# Running Tomcat 5.5 with JDK 1.4

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, java

We have one application which needs to be run on JDK 1.4
I have been searching for quite some time, I couldn't find any resource how to make Tomcat v5.5 use JDK 1.4

As per Running.txt, It can run on JDK 1.4 and needs compatiable package, but what it's, where to download is not there.

Can any one help me with download links for Tomcat v5.5 which can run on JDK 1.4 out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.36/bin/ (or whatever version you require) has the "compat" package along with the main distributions, you should just be able to download that and then unpack it on top of the main distribution to put the required JAR files in `common/endorsed`.

Comment: Hi.

I copied bin/jmx.jar to bin folder and pasted common folder under main tomcat directory. Still it's giving same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer should be there:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/building.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, It is great that you have found a possible solution to this question, but it is customary to include the specific information that solves the questions problems as part of your answer, and keep the link as reference, as opposed to simply linking an external site. Please edit your question with what you believe is the relevant information from the website.